# Parse Push Notifications bundle display name vs bundle id issue

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My app is setup in a way of which it has a different bundle display name than its bundle ID. This causes an issue when working with Push notifications of which the user is not in the app and receives a push notifications, the title of the notification is that of the bundle display name, but when the user receives a push notification and is in the app, the title of the notification is that of the bundle ID. Obviously, this is a discrepancy...my questions are as follow:

- Is there a way to make these titles the same (= to the bundle display
  name) on Parse Push?
- If not, is there an alternate solution to this not on parse?
- Can I control to display the push notifications the user receives
  depending on whether or not the app is open or not? For example, if it was received while the app was open, don't display it. If received when the app is closed, do dispaly it.

Changing my app's bundle ID does not seem like a solution since it is already        live on the app store and has accumulated a significant amount of users and reviews.

Need some help on this one!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue like so:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        //app is in foreground
        //the push is in your control
        //dont do anything
        NSLog(@"got push, but not displaying it");

    } else {
        [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
        //app is in background:
        //iOS is responsible for displaying push alerts, banner etc..
    }

}
```